# Cannot retrieve image in browser when using OAuth token and Jira

Tags: cookies, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

I am building a frontend client for Jira and am running into some conflicting authentication methods I think.

I have setup the OAuth2 authentication method for logging in and hitting the Jira API. I have a button on a login page that redirects to Jira, you log in, hit "allow" and are redirected to my app. This step completes fine, I have a token and a secret and can make api calls just fine.

Next, I make an api call to get the user data, which returns fine. One of the pieces of data is a set of avatar urls. I put one of the urls into my site's markup. Here is where the problem begins.

If my browser session that I used to login is still active, I get an avatar. BUT if not, I get an "anonymous" avatar from Jira.

All the while, my OAuth token/api calls all seem to return fine.

This makes sense as Jira is using cookie based auth and I am not. So if that cookie dies in my browser, the call to the image will fail.

My ultimate question is how to handle this? Is this my responsibility to put an expiration on the token? What happens if they select "Stay logged in"? I don't think I get that knowledge on the OAuth side.

I kind of feel like I am missing something but I cannot figure out what. This seems like a problem that has been fixed or isn't even really a problem.

One solution would be just to switch to a cookie based authentication but OAuth seems more secure.

I've also tried directly hitting it from my server but that also yields an anon avatar. As does a curl with the access token. Maybe I didn't provide it in the correct way?

Any thoughts or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.